# Add the same point to all subplots

Tags: python, subplot

I have a program that shows 8 subplots, all log-log graphs with different data from 8 different files.

I have combined all the data and calculated a mean. Now, I have a single point with specific x and y coordinates I want to plot onto every graph. I'm having trouble doing this, all my subplots plot as part of a loop and I don't calculate the mean until the very end (once all the data files have been read) so need to find a way to plot this point onto existing subplots.

at the end of my loop I tried what I thought would be an obvious (but inefficient) way to plot this:

```
if plotnum in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]:
    plt.plot(np.log(100),np.log(mean_length),'ro')
```

where 100 is my set x value and mean_length is my set y value, but this isn't working.

any ideas?

Comment: can you paste the full code or a bigger part of the code?

Comment: It may be easier to use [subplots](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots) ie. `fig, axs = plt.subplots(...)` that way you can add the plot to each axis after.

Comment: Rather than saying "this isn't working" (which could mean almost anything), it would be better to be more specific about how the result differs from what you were hoping for. "Nothing happens", "it replaces all my plots with just a single point", "the extra point is shown only in the even-numbered subplots", "my computer explodes", whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to loop through the different axes that you have.

You didn't post your graph-generating code, so I'll make some up:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
all_axes = []
for idx in range(1,10):
    ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, idx)
    ax.plot([1,2,3], [10, 30, 80])
    all_axes.append(ax)
```

Now we have a bunch of graphs, and you want to include a single point in each of them. So loop through these axes, and add this point!

```
for ax in all_axes:
    ax.scatter([4.6], [20])
```

And to make the graphs update:

```
plt.draw()
```

Comment: thanks! used a loop to plot all my data onto subplots (area vs. length) and used append to then calculate a mean length from all 8 data files. then used this second loop to plot my specific x and y coordinate point onto every graph

`mean_length=round(np.mean(LL),3)
plotnum=1
for plotnum in range(1,9):
    plt.subplot(2,4,plotnum)
    plt.plot(np.log(100),np.log(mean_length),'ro')`